# Excel VBA pass variable between functions

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to write excel VBA code that will parse column B (analyst login time), and if that column is 0 (as in they were out that day), it will update the adjacent columns to say NA.  Currently, the below code errors out.  If I change the rng variable in Cells(rng, i) to a number, then the code will take that number (let's say 4) and put NA in all of the fields (3 to 23, so, C to W).  I believe that the issue is that the value of rng is not being passed into the inner function, but I do not know how to get arround this.

```
Dim rng As Range
For Each rng In Range("B4:B10")
    If rng.Value = 0 Then
        For i = 3 To 23
            Cells(rng, i).Value = NA
        Next i
    End If
Next rng
```

Comment: Perhaps you want #N/A which is creatable with `=CVErr(2042)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`rng` on its own (without an explicit property name) defaults to returning `.Value` which when `0` tries to use row index `0` which is not valid, instead get the row number via `.Row`:

```
Cells(rng.Row, i).Value = "NA"
```

If `NA` is not a variable but a string, quote it.

Non-loop alternative:

```
 If rng.Value = 0 Then Range(rng.Offset(0, 1), rng.Offset(0, 21)).Value = "NA"
```

Comment: Yes, thank you, that worked.  I had quotes around the NA, but forgot to copy them here.  However, the rng.Row is what fixed it.

Answer (score 0):

Problem is here:

```
Cells(rng, i).Value = "NA"
```

why you give range to place where Number (row number) must go?

You need to use

```
Cells(rng.Row, i).Value = "NA"
```